# what rights/permissions does a file need to be viewed in a webbroswer

Tags: linux, browser, permissions, file-permissions

Probably a basic questuion, but, I get the following when I visit a webpage I am working on, so the image is not displayed in the browser.

`animacionloading.gif:1 GET http://172.21.200.37/username/dir1/animacionloading.gif 403 (Forbidden)`

This is the premissions on the file:

```
$ls -l dir1/
total 432
-rwx------ 1 username username 359032 Apr 29 08:15 animacionloading.gif
```

Now I can do a `chmod 777 animacionloading.gif` which gives me these permissions `-rwxrwxrwx 1 username username 359032 Apr 29 08:15 animacionloading.gif`
and then I can view the image in the the browser.

My question is what is the minimum rights the file needs to be viewed in the browser?

I have some understanding of the following [terms](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions), but just not in this case. Would `All Users` be anyone that visits the webpage? And would they only need read permissions?

- u - Owner
- g - Group
- o or a - All Users
- r - Read
- w - Write
- x - Execute

**EDIT1** for my ref, the following will allow the files be seen in the browser.

`$ chmod 004 LoadingBasketContents.gif loop.gif`

`-------r-- 1 username username  45592 Apr 29 09:05 LoadingBasketContents.gif
-------r-- 1 username username  25465 Apr 29 09:05 loop.gif`

Comment: Only the user the webserver runs under (often `apache` or `httpd`) needs to be able to read the file. "All users" in a chmod context means, all users with a Linux/Unix account on that server. The webserver serves the file to people on the Internet, and decides who gets to see it and who doesn't. The filesystem permissions don't play into that.

Comment: then how come if i change the group premissions I can see it in the browser? how does this relate to apache or httpd?

Comment: If you change the group permissions, the web server's user gets access to it. That user wasn't able to access to the file when you restricted the permissions. This is normally solved by e.g. having the file owner user and the web server user in the same group... don't know where one might find a comprehensive guide for this stuff

Comment: Here is one article that might be useful http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache